# Converting Typesafe Config type to java.util.Properties

Tags: java, scala, typesafe

The title talks by itself, I have a Config object (from https://github.com/typesafehub/config) and I want to pass it the a constructor which only supports java.util.Properties as argument.
Is there an easy way to convert a Config to a Properties object ?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a way to convert a typesafe *Config* object into a *Properties* java object. I have only tested it in a simple case for creating Kafka properties.

Given this configuration in **application.conf**

```
kafka-topics {
  my-topic {
    zookeeper.connect = "localhost:2181",
    group.id = "testgroup",
    zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = "500",
    zookeeper.sync.time.ms = "250",
    auto.commit.interval.ms = "1000"
  }
}
```

You can create the corresponding *Properties* object like that:

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
import java.util.Properties
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig

object Application extends App {

  def propsFromConfig(config: Config): Properties = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

    val props = new Properties()

    val map: Map[String, Object] = config.entrySet().map({ entry =>
      entry.getKey -> entry.getValue.unwrapped()
    })(collection.breakOut)

    props.putAll(map)
    props
  }

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  val consumerConfig = {
    val topicConfig = config.getConfig("kafka-topics.my-topic")
    val props = propsFromConfig(topicConfig)
    new ConsumerConfig(props)
  }

  // ...    
}
```

The function *propsFromConfig* is what you are mainly interested in, and the key points are the use of *entrySet* to get a flatten list of properties, and the *unwrapped* of the entry value, that gives an Object which type depends on the configuration value.

Answer (score 4):

You can try my scala wrapper https://github.com/andr83/scalaconfig. Using it convert config object to java Properties is simple:

```
val properties = config.as[Properties]
```

Comment: This should be part of Config imho

Answer (score 1):

As `typesafe config`/`hocon` supports a much richer structure than `java.util.propeties` it will be hard to get a safe conversion.

Or spoken otherwise as `properties` can only express a subset of `hocon` the conversion is not clear, as it will have a possible information loss.

So if you configuration is rather flat and does not contain `utf-8` then you could transform `hocon` to `json` and then extract the values.

A better solution would be to implement a `ConfigClass` and populate the values with values from hocon and passing this to the class you want to configure.

Comment: Yes, I know about this data model mismatch. I was hoping that Config or ConfigObject might have a kind of "flatten" method. Actually, I want to configure a Kafka consumer from my config object, and Kafka consumer takes a Properties as argument; so I'm more or less sure the part of my config going to the consumer will not be nested.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible directly through typesafe config. Even rending the entire hocon file into json does provide a true valid json:
ex:

```
"play" : {
    "filters" : {
            "disabled" : ${?play.filters.disabled}[
            "play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter"
        ],
            "disabled" : ${?play.filters.disabled}[
            "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"
        ]

    }
}
```

That format is directly from `Config.render`

as you can see, `disabled` is represented twice with hocon style syntax.

I have also had problems with rendering hocon -> json -> hocon

Example hocon:

```
  http {
   port = "9000"
   port = ${?HTTP_PORT}
 }
```

typesafe config would parse this to

```
{
  "http": {
    "port": "9000,${?HTTP_PORT}"
  }
}
```

However if you try to parse that in hocon - it throws a syntax error. the `,` cannot be there.
The hocon correct parsing would be `9000${?HTTP_PORT}` - with no comma between the values. I believe this is true for all array concatenation and substitution